# ServerVersion threw an error of the type system.invalidoperation exception while connecting to Redshift cluster from C#

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-redshift

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();


            // Server, e.g. "examplecluster.xyz.us-west-2.redshift.amazonaws.com"
            string server = "examplecluster.xyz.us-west-2.redshift.amazonaws.com";

            // Port, e.g. "5439"
            string port = "5439";

            // MasterUserName, e.g. "masteruser".
            string masterUsername = "*****";

            // MasterUserPassword, e.g. "mypassword".
            string masterUserPassword = "*****";

            // DBName, e.g. "dev"
            string DBName = "dev";

            string query = "select * from suppliers";

            try
            {

                string connString = "Driver={Amazon Redshift (x64)};" +
                   String.Format("Server={0};Database={1};" +
                   "UID={2};PWD={3};Port={4};SSL=true;Sslmode=Require",
                   server, DBName, masterUsername,
                   masterUserPassword, port);
                using (OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(connString))
                {

                    conn.Open();

                    string sql = query;
                    OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(sql, conn);
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    dt = ds.Tables[0];

                    conn.Close();
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
        }
    }
}
```

Was trying this code to connect to my redshift cluster but getting issue while connecting as serversion threw an exception system.invalidoperation[image],any other way to connect to the redshift through .net that would be prefered,i have already added the ODBC for amazon in my project

Comment: you forget to place a question mark and other punctuation in your question so it is hard to read anyway what was the message of that invalidoperation exaption it will be helpful if you post it along is there any inner exceptions post their messages too

Comment: i can't see you image because of my corporate firwall settings anyway images of exceptions are useless

Comment: exception is conn.serversion threw an exception of type System.invalidoperationException   @vasily.sib

Comment: ok what is a message of this exception?

Comment: there is no message thats the only thing that is shown @vasily.sib

Comment: any exceptions have a `Message` property

Comment: _COMPlusExceptionCode = -532462766

Comment: no we still need the message your code -532462766 = 0xE0434352 which is an exception code of all .net exception

Comment: @vasily.sib with this there comes null in exception in that scenario from where would you get a message

Comment: oh, i tired to ignore punctuations in my comments :( Where is this exception is thrown? At which exactly line of your code? Do you catch it? It can't be null in catch block.

Comment: when i do conn.open im taken directly to the catch block and its null just has the exceptioncode when i dig into it

Comment: add `var exception = ex.ToString(); Debug.WriteLine(exception);` to your `catch` block and debug it. What is in `exception`?

Comment: ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified @vasily.sib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have been able to sort it out the issue was due to wrong odbc driver version being used ,was working with a 64-bit version where as IIS was a 32-bit  changed the ODBC version to 32 and it worked